# What is the difference between having a Circle object to a CircleMapObject or CircleShape in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, geometry

I don't know if this is a silly question or not but because there are different types of circle objects in which you can have, from studying the Libgdx API I've found that the CircleMapObject has more functions relating to the object such as color, visibility etc than the Circle and CircleShape objects. My question is what would be the reason to declare the shape as one of these type of objects over the other? Are there any performance constraints on the program depending on the type of circle object you create or do they have the same effect in terms of performance and it's just down to personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleMapObject is intended to be used with the Maps api. It holds a Circle, and a few additional properties as defined by its parent class MapObject. CircleShape is for use with Box2D.

Circle is the most light weight and general, so if you don't need it for a Map or Box2D, that's the one you want.